# Perl soap request retrieving one value?

Tags: perl, soap

I have the following script that apparently this will not let me submit with more detail.  It basically is pulling basic scheduling details from a SOAP request into XML and i need to retrieve a value from it.:

```
#!perl
#
# Quick sample script to fetch data from Tribune's Data Direct Service
#
# R. Eden 2/23/08
# (modified from XMLTV's tv_grab_na_dd, which started with a sample)
# script provided by Tribune

use SOAP::Lite;
use strict;

my $USER='username';
my $PASS='password';
my $START='2016-09-27T00:00:00Z';
my $STOP ='2016-09-27T23:59:59Z';

#
# Set login credientials
#
sub SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::get_basic_credentials {
return lc($USER) => "$PASS";
}


#
# Deifne SOAP service
#
my $dd_service='http://dd.schedulesdirect.org/tech/tmsdatadirect/schedulesdirect/tvDataDelivery.wsdl';
my $proxy='http://localhost/';
my $soap= SOAP::Lite
       -> service($dd_service)
    -> outputxml('true')
    -> proxy($proxy, options => {compress_threshold => 10000,
                                 timeout            => 420});

#
# It's polite to set an agent string
#
$soap->transport->agent("perl/$0");


#
# Now let's get our data
#
my $raw_data=$soap->download($START,$STOP);


print $raw_data;

exit 0;
```

---

It outputs:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:SOAP-ENC='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'>
<SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:downloadResponse SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' xmlns:ns1='urn:TMSWebServices'>
<xtvdResponse xsi:type='ns1:xtvdResponse'>

<messages xsi:type='ns1:messages'>

<message>Your subscription will expire: 2017-09-29T21:18:20Z</message>

</messages>
<xtvd from='2016-09-27T00:00:00Z' to='2016-09-27T23:59:59Z' schemaVersion='1.3' xmlns='urn:TMSWebServices' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='urn:TMSWebServices http://dd.schedulesdirect.org/tech/xml/schemas/tmsxtvd.xsd'>

<stations>
</stations>
<lineups>
</lineups>
</xtvd>
</xtvdResponse>
</ns1:downloadResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope> [
```

---

I strictly want to date/time of the `<message>` part that says:

```xml
<message>Your subscription will expire: 2017-09-29T21:18:20Z</message>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: How firm are you with Perl? Have you modified that apparently existing script yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most pragmatic way would be to just take the raw result that contains the XML as a string, and parse it with a regular expression. All you want is a fixed pattern, so there is no need to actually use an XML parser (or the built-in stuff that SOAP::Lite brings).

```
$raw_data =~ m/Your subscription will expire: ([^<]+)</;
my $date_string = $1;
```

Now you have `2017-09-29T21:18:20Z` inside of `$date_string` and can do with it what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I tried as you suggest and when I print $date_string; It returns nothing.

Comment: @John there was a `+` missing. Typo on my side, sorry.

Comment: Thanks simbabque.  Still no joy with the plus sign in there.

Comment: @John it's typo-day for me today -.- I put a `}` instead of the `+`, then added the `+` and didn't remove the `}`... (facepalm)

Comment: heck yeah!!! Thanks simbabque.  That did it.  Now to start working on the real program. :)  This was the start of a Nagios monitoring app I'm creating.

Comment: @john great. Pay attention to every character. They make a difference. :-)